# Vector of fn pointers doesn't reveal correct size()

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a vector of function pointers that is default initialized as a class member, so it always has 2 elements. However, when reading its `size()` I get gibberish. I have created a trivial, minimal replication of this problem below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using fnptr = float (*)(float);

float fn1(float x){ return x;};
float fn2(float x){ return x;};

std::vector<fnptr> fnptrs(){
  std::vector<fnptr> ret;
  ret.push_back(&fn1);
  ret.push_back(&fn2);
  return ret;
}

class Foo{ 
public:

  int nFns()const{
    return fns.size();
  }

private:
  std::vector<fnptr> fns = fnptrs(); // always initialized
};


class Baz {
public:
  explicit Baz(Foo f):foo{&f}{}

  const Foo* foo; // my problem does not appear if this is not a pointer

}; 

class Bar {
public:
  explicit Bar(Foo f):foo{f}{
    bazs.push_back(Baz(foo)); 
    bazs.push_back(Baz(foo)); 
  }

  void viewSizes()const{
    for (auto& i:bazs)
      std::cout << " i.foo->nFns() = " << i.foo->nFns() << "\n";
  }

  const Foo foo;
  std::vector<Baz> bazs;

}; 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  Foo f;
  Bar b(f);

  b.viewSizes();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 i.foo->nFns() = -677271344
 i.foo->nFns() = -516
```

I do not prefer to store Foo in Baz as a pointer, but in my real program, I have a vector of Baz's that is swapped out frequently and a reference cannot be used for that (doesn't compile). If I make it a regular member (not a pointer or reference) then I have no problems, but with large numbers of these objects its better not to store the same copy in every object, so a pointer is what I need to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
 explicit Baz(Foo f):foo{&f}{}
```

`f` is a local variable of the constructor and evaporates once the constructor exits. You probably want to pass a reference, or an actual raw pointer instead.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct but in my non-trivial program I am actually using a reference and I forgot to make that a reference in this trivialized example. That solves the problem for this example, so I need to try and recreate the problem better as a minimal example.

Comment: I believe this steered me in the right direction. My problem was similar to what you describe, thanks.